# best method to get all call stacks in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to get automatic call stacks in huge django web app, on run time, avoiding duplication. What I am trying to do is write decorator (Ex. - `@get_call_stack`) for any class, method (including the classes in `models.py`, etc). Only decorated entities will get tracked on runtime. Is this approach really feasible, if the app is huge? Also, what would be the best, and optimized storage medium for storing all such stacks?